# How to migrate *JUST* the microsoft account Windows 10 installation?

Tags: windows-10, installation

I'm attempting to set up a number of basically equal machines.

All will be using the same software and same settings for that software.
However, some software can't just be installed "globally" for the PC and then expected to work for the target user. I attempted that and got stuck with e.g. Chrome installing itself into current user's appdata. Please insert any number of additional programs here that do similar stuff.

So I'm attempting to set up a "real" user here, but I'm guessing that is going to prevent me from reusing the same disk image as Office 365 installation alone carries the user's signature with it. Again - any additional number of other software doing similar.

So, is there an approach I could use where I could at the end of setup simply set the correct target Microsoft account and have everything properly working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows utility that will help here is
[sysprep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--system-preparation--overview).

This utility will erase the current login account and prepare the system for
deployment, allowing you to use
[DISM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism---deployment-image-servicing-and-management-technical-reference-for-windows)
to capture an image of the installation.

For Office 365, once its installation is complete, log back into your
Office 365 account and remove the license.
Once the image is deployed on a computer,
on its first launch Office will demand to be activated.
For more information see the article
[How to Create a Windows Image with Office 365 Software Installed](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/45080-how-to-create-a-windows-image-with-office-365-software-installed).

A simple-minded alternate solution is to use any cloning product to clone the disk,
changing manually the login and Office 365 sign-in on the cloned computers.